# CSS - Responsive Relative Flex Divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I've recently been practicing some CSS and have been making some progress, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a div mobile-responsive if its position is set to *relative* and it is contained within another div that is set to *display: flex;*.

I tried modifying the left and right margins on the divs, but this didn't seem to have the desired effect of making the div resize when the viewport is resized to simulate a small or mobile device's screen.

If someone wouldn't mind taking a quick peak at my code to see where I may be missing something or where I may have went wrong, I'd greatly appreciate the assistance! (And if anyone happens to have any general advice regarding my code, that would also be appreciated - I'm not the best with CSS so any feedback would certainly be appreciated!)

Please see below for my HTML and CSS code.

Thanks,

Jamie

```css
body{
  background-color: #bed3f4;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.logo{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: cursive;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile_image{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #c2c4c6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}

.profile_box{
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.name{
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.user_bio{
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: Arial;
}

.user_social_icons{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Personal Profile Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">Profile Page</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="profile_box">

        <div class="name">Jamie McGibbon</div>

        <div class="user_bio">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper nulla id leo eleifend, in mattis diam pretium. Proin pellentesque ultrices consectetur. Etiam eget magna leo. Aliquam condimentum nisi leo, vel cursus lorem placerat vitae.</p>

          <p>Quisque pulvinar id sapien eu dapibus. Vestibulum risus dui, aliquam sit amet congue non, egestas a leo. Nam sed eleifend diam. Nullam ultrices vel dolor et mattis. Praesent eu euismod nisl. Ut quis dolor risus. Proin sem diam, hendrerit in dui sit amet, faucibus vulputate ex. Curabitur molestie rhoncus ligula varius scelerisque.</p>

          <div class="user_social_icons">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-reddit-square fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-youtube-square fa-3x"></i>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="profile_image"></div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What *specifically* should be happening that is not currently happening? And I'm assuming the `<div>` in question is the grey box?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - Currently, when the page is resized to be smaller, the white box doesn't scale to fit within the available space, causing the "user bio" text to get cut off. I'd like that white box to scale so that users don't have to scroll horizontally on smaller devices/screens.

Comment: Instead of using fixed widths, try using percentages or media queries.

Comment: @sol - Thanks for the reply. That seems to work for the horizontal scroll, but introduces a new issue - when I resize the window horizontally to simulate a mobile device's screen, the text and social icons flow out of the white <div>. I tried changing the height of that white <div> to a percentage, but that didn't seem to work. Sorry for all the questions, but if you could perhaps point me in the right direction with the vertical overflow, that'd be appreciated too! Thanks!

Comment: Setting `width: 100%` on `.user_bio` seems to work for me :) Keep in mind that you have a few other fixed widths in there as well, which may need adjusting to suit :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge That helps, thanks! I appreciate your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions..

You can remove positioning rules here. `text-align` seems to do what you need. Remove fixed width and height from the main content, that's what's causing overflow of child elements.

Happy to answer further questions.

```css
body {
  background-color: #bed3f4;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: cursive;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.profile_image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #c2c4c6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.profile_box {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.user_bio {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.user_social_icons {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">Profile Page</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="profile_image"></div>
  <div class="profile_box">

    <div class="name">Jamie McGibbon</div>

    <div class="user_bio">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper nulla id leo eleifend, in mattis diam pretium. Proin pellentesque ultrices consectetur. Etiam eget magna leo. Aliquam condimentum nisi leo, vel cursus lorem placerat vitae.</p>

      <p>Quisque pulvinar id sapien eu dapibus. Vestibulum risus dui, aliquam sit amet congue non, egestas a leo. Nam sed eleifend diam. Nullam ultrices vel dolor et mattis. Praesent eu euismod nisl. Ut quis dolor risus. Proin sem diam, hendrerit in dui
        sit amet, faucibus vulputate ex. Curabitur molestie rhoncus ligula varius scelerisque.</p>

      <div class="user_social_icons">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-reddit-square fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-youtube-square fa-3x"></i>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



</div>
```